# Designing classes (beginner). How to design Association

Tags: vb.net, oop, architecture

I have a "Customer" class and a "Source File" class.
"Source file" never exists without the "Customer"
"Customer" has multiple "Source Files"

Does UploadSourceFile method, belongs to "Customer" class or "Source File" class?

I understand that "Customer" should have an attribute "Source files" (list of source file).
Should class "Source file" also have "Customer" attribute?

Comment: What programming language you are using?

Comment: vb.net. didn't think that would be important

Comment: Seems like Customer and SourceFile contains the data. UploadSourceFile might be in an other class used for data transfer. This method would take a customer or a sourcefile as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion (and generally speaking), if source files belongs to the customer, as you say, the method has to be putted in the Customer, not in the Source File. Customer contains a list of Source File and a method to insert a Source File in that list. The method UploadSourceFile is something like:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.addSourceFile("filename");
```

Another approch, always in my opionion, is to put the method UploadSourceFile in the SourceFile class as a static method. Because in that case, UploadSourceFile doesn't belong to ONE SPECIFIC SourceFile. It is a sort of general method to upload (and so create) a file. In this case you'll have something like:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.addSourceFile(SourceFileClass.uploadSourceFile());
```